# How can I compare the date objects in JScript of Enterprise Architect?

Tags: javascript, vbscript, jscript, enterprise-architect

I made jscript which runs through elements in package and now I need to add comparison of element.created with today. How can I make this?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the following code and modify accordingly

```
// get the date from the element
var dateCreated = new Date(theElement.Created);

// remove the hours, minutes, seconds, miliseconds
dateCreated.setHours(0,0,0,0);

// create the date object to compare
// input parameter is yyyy, mm, dd
// please note that the mm starts from 0 for January
var dateToCompare = new Date(2013, 0, 13);

// sample usage
if (dateCreated > dateToCompare)
{
    Session.Output("Creation date is newer");
}
else if (dateCreated < dateToCompare)
{
    Session.Output("Creation date is older");
}
else
{
    Session.Output("Creation date match");
}
```